# Can I load or specify locally an Ansible Playbook in Tower?

Tags: ansible, gitlab, ansible-tower

The template I'm running is loading the Playbook from a GitLab repository.
Is there a way to specify the Playbook content directly in Tower or pull it directly from my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

The playbook directory is decided by 'Project' in Tower.
**Steps:**

- Create a directory in /var/lib/awx/projects directory on the local ansible machine. Example, /var/lib/awx/projects/project1
- Place the playbook in 'project1' directory. Example, var/lib/awx/projects/project1/example_playbook.yml (follow process as described [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/projects.html#manage-playbooks-manually))
- Create a manual project in Tower (follow process as described [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/projects.html#add-a-new-project))
- Use that project in job template to see the playbook 'example_playbook.yml'

Answer (score 0):

To add onto the previous answer, you can only have 1 inventory per template. So if you have some playbooks in Git, and more playbooks locally you will have to create a template for each of the playbooks. You can combine the two playbooks into a workflow though.